# Is it possible that User Session States might overlap, resulting in one user reading the session state of another one

Tags: asp.net, session-state

We have a web appliaction where we are nonintoxicating users in a log in form, after log in, we are keeping the user info ( user info, user id, ...) in a session state, now under pressure, sometimes and very rarely we get from clients that they are logging in with their user name, but after login they found themselves with some boy else's name, and reading their data, as if they are reading other user's session. Could this be the issue?

Comment: You need to give us some piece of code or explain in more detail the problem. Overlapping user session states is not probable at all since they are made to be one for each user.

Comment: Nonintoxicating users? Bad autocorrect? :)

Comment: Do you have any static variables that might not be cleaned properly? Application variables?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your code, use of statics, application variables or caching. No it's not possible under normal conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could see that happening is if they somehow shared the same session ID, which would probably only happen if you're managing session state in SQL server. If you're using standard InProc session state, that would be highly unlikely.